# PrimeFaces autocomplete groupBy only works with sorted entries

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using the PrimeFaces [autoComplete](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml?jfwid=0764e) with the groupBy function.

```html
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete placeholder="Select something"
                    size="27"
                    dropdown="true"
                    forceSelection="true"
                    var="value"
                    itemLabel="#{value}"
                    itemValue="#{value}"
                    value="#{autoCompleteGroupByBean.selection}"
                    completeMethod="#{autoCompleteGroupByBean.complete}"
                    groupBy="#{autoCompleteGroupByBean.getGroup(value)}" />
</h:form>
```

```java
package org.primefaces.test.view;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Setter
@Getter
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AutoCompleteGroupByBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> values;
    private List<String> groups;
    private String selection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        values = Arrays.asList(
                "ABC value0", "ABC value1", "ABC value2", "ABC value3",
                "DEF value0", "DEF value1", "DEF value2", "DEF value3",
                "GHI value0", "GHI value1", "GHI value2", "GHI value3");
        // If the values are not ordered, groups are occuring multiple times
        // Collections.shuffle(values);
        groups = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
    }

    public List<String> complete(final String query) {
        return values.stream()
                .filter(v -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(v, query))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getGroup(final String value) {
        return groups.stream()
                .filter(g -> StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(value, g))
                .findAny()
                .orElse("MISC");
    }
}
```

It works correct if the values are ordered:

[image: AutoComplete with ordered values]

If the values are not ordered (I used `Collections.shuffle()` in the example to do that), groups are occuring multiple times:

[image: AutoComplete with not ordered values]

In my real project I am getting the values from an external service and the groups are not always at the beginning of the entry like in the example.
Is there any way to avoid the duplicate groups or do I need to sort all values in advance?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If sorting solves the problem, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested I solved this by sorting all values by group.

The `groupBy` is not documented in the PrimeFaces documentation. It would have been easier to understand, that the values need to be sorted for this to work.